# Does Creative Commons ShareAlike condition apply to Collective Works?

Tags: copyright, creative-commons, photography

If an image with a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 2.0 Generic license ([CC BY-SA 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/)) is used in a `Collective Work` such as an article, online slideshow, or book.  Does the book, article, or slideshow need to be released under the same license as the image?

I believe a `Collective Work` is not considered a `Derivative Work` (and thus not subject to `Derivative Work` restrictions) but I'm not clear whether a `Collective Work` is subject to [`Share Alike`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Share-alike) restrictions.

Also, does the answer to this vary at all with the different versions of the CC BY-SA (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Don't overthink this:

> If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.

Have you remixed, transformed or built upon the material? If you put a picture in your article to illustrate a point made in that article then no. If you drew a moustache on the portrait then yes.

Comment: What if the point hes making depends on the unmodified picture heavily? Wouldn't that be considered to 'build upon' the material?